# dotnet ubuntu14.04 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Thread' could not be found

Tags: .net, multithreading, ubuntu-14.04, coreclr

I installed Dotnet on  ubuntu.14.04-x64 by following instructions on "http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/". Then I wrote a simple code for threading,

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace mythread
{
public class threader
{
    public static void thread1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread1 value: {0}.", i);
        }
    }
    public static void thread2()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread2 value: {0}.", j);
        }
    }
}

public class class1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    ThreadStart t1 = new ThreadStart(threader.thread1);
    ThreadStart t2 = new ThreadStart(threader.thread2);
    Thread tr1 = new Thread(t1);
    Thread tr2 = new Thread(t2);
    tr1.Start();
    tr2.Start();
    }
}
}
```

After running this code I'm getting error
"error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Thread' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".
Can anybody help me resolve it?

My project.json is

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-rc2-23811"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
      "System.Threading": "4.0.11-rc2-23811",
        "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.11-rc2-23811"
            }
        }
    },
     "configurations": {
    "Debug": {
      "compilationOptions": {
        "define": ["DEBUG", "TRACE"]
      }
    },
    "Release": {
      "compilationOptions": {
        "define": ["RELEASE", "TRACE"],
        "optimize": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to version assemblies and packages.

"look at the myget dev feed for the package: https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/dotnet-core. More docs about how this is all made is coming as part of https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5453."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reference to `System.Threading.Thread` in `project.json`